# Setting jQuery offset().top

Tags: jquery

How do I **set** y location using jQ offset().top?

`$(#ele).offset().top = 123`

Do I need to include 'px' or other appropriate unit in there?

Comment: `$('#ele').css('top', '123px');`

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using css here, is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset2)

> .offset( coordinates )
>
> coordinates: An object containing the
> properties top and left, which are integers indicating the new top and
> left coordinates for the elements.

The properties `top` and `left` are integers, you don't need to include the 'px' unit

```
$("#ele").offset({ top: 123 });
```